# What is the best way to show different content on the same thank-you page used by multiple forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, query-string

I have made a contact form as part of a Wordpress plugin. I have set up a thank-you page and after a successful submission, the user is redirected to that thank-you page via `wp_redirect`.

The thank-you page is supposed to be the same for multiple forms, but the content on that page should change depending on which form the user has submitted.

For example: if a user has submitted a booking form, the message on the thank-you page should be *"Thank you for you booking"*. If the user has submitted a contact form, the message should be *"Thank you for your message"* etc.

At the moment I'm adding a query string to the thank-you page URL and I use `$_GET` to decide which message to show:

`https://my-site.com/confirmation/?order-form=book-showcase`

```
/**
* Confirmation page shortcode
* Shortcode: [fy_confirmation_page]
*/
add_shortcode('fy_confirmation_page', 'fy_confirmation_page_shortcode');

function fy_confirmation_page_shortcode() {

    $query_param = htmlspecialchars($_GET["order-form"]);

    switch($query_param) {
        case 'book-showcase':
            _e('Thank you for you booking', 'fy-one');
            break;
        case 'contact':
            _e('Thank you for your message', 'fy-one');
            break;
        default:
            _e('You haven\'t submitted a form', 'fy-one');
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. The problem is, that the thank-you page can be accessed, and the static message can be seen, even if the user hasn't completed a submission. I don't want that.

What is a better way to make a thank you page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a name/id for every form button and then check if that button was clicked. Like this:

```
<form>  //form 1
<input .....>
<button type="submit" name="but_1" id="but_1">Submit</button>
</form>

<form>   //form 2
<input .....>
<button type="submit" name="but_2" id="but_2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then:

```
if(isset($_POST['but_1']))
{
   //do smth
}
else
if(isset($_POST['but_2']))
{
   //do smth
}
```

Comment: No, I can't access that. The form submission is executed on the page where the form is, while the thank you page is a different page. I would have to use a session to do what you propose, but I'm not really sure if that's a great idea.